# WordPress - how to insert html code selectively in posts

Tags: wordpress, post, filter

I want to display custom html code when a post is rendered (so not when is inserted into the database).

I currently do this with `add_filter('the_content', 'my_custom_method')`. The only problem is that I want this do be displayed  only inside the post (when is viewed in its own page), not when all posts are rendered .

I banged my head against the wall, but couldn't find any method to tell me if i'm currently inside an individual post or not (this has to work for every url rewriting possible, so i can't rely on url)

Is there such a method? I believe it should be, but i can't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function for checking if the post is in its own page is `is_single()`

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_custom_method');

function my_custom_method(){
    if(is_single()){
        //code for your custom html code
    }
}
```

the function `is_single()` checks if the page being rendered is a single page or not.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to modify your templates.  Wordpress template sets should have a file named `single.php` (inside `wp-content/themes/<theme name>`).  This is the page that gets rendered when you are viewing the page for a single post.

You could edit this file and insert whatever you needed to for the posts there.

Comment: thank you! unfortunetly i can mark only one answer  as accepted answer, though both answers are great. Thanks!